# Dynamically altering variable during execution in Robot Scripts

Tags: python, robotframework

I am writing a robot script, that can navigate through a page asking for an One-Time-Password (OTP). The flow is the script will open an application, and then it will wait for an OTP, and I will manually enter the OTP into the robot script for it to continue to run. However, it is not working for me.

Here is what I have so far:

**test.robot**

```
***Settings***
Variables       OTP.py

***Test Cases***
Open Application
    Open Application 

Enter OTP
    Sleep       5
    Input Text      textbox      ${otp}
```

**OTP.py**

```
otp = "12345"
```

So what I am trying to do, is run the application, and when the app reaches the page where it prompts for an OTP, during the sleep (5), I will change the value of the OTP in OTP.py so that the robot script will call the correct value, to proceed on. However, it always returns the previous value (before changing, 12345 in this case).

Does anyone have any idea I can dynamically change the value during the execution? Appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, best solution for user input during test would be `Dialogs` library which is part of standard libraries. So your case would look like:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Dialogs

*** Keywords ***
Enter OTP
    ${otp}    Get Value From User    Please provide OTP code
    Input Text      textbox      ${otp}
```

But this solution is far from being reliable and depends on user interaction. Better solution would be writing custom python keyword using `pyotp` that would generate OTP codes for your. Sample example of such keyword could be the following:

```py
# OTPCodes.py
import pyotp


class OTPCodes:

    def generate_otp_code(self, secret):
        totp = pyotp.TOTP(secret)
        return totp.now()
```

and in robot:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    OTPCodes.py

*** Keywords ***
Enter OTP
    ${otp}    Generate Otp Code    <SECRET>
    Input Text      textbox      ${otp}
```

Even better solution would be not passing `SECRET` as argument, but obtaining it from environment variables.